# Bootstrap not toggling the dropdown box

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I currently have a navbar that I want to incorporate a dropdown into. Following the Bootstrap v5 tutorial I have the include ' data-bs-toggle="dropdown" ' and include the dropdown-toggle into a span. The dropdown-menu was also defined. The problem that I am having is that the dropdown is not toggling and displaying.

This is the code I am trying to apply. I am using react.

```
<li className="nav-item dropdown text-center mx-2 mx-lg-1 ">
        <span className=" nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" >
          <Link to="#" style={{textDecoration:"none"}} >
            <div>
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-person-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z"/>
                <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z"/>
              </svg>
            </div>
            Dropdown
          </Link>
          
        </span>
        <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <li><Link className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</Link></li>
          <li><Link className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</Link></li>
          <li><Link className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```